# Why is my password hashing function producing different hashes with the same salt?

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core-mvc, password-encryption

Passwords stored in my database are encrypted like this:

```
byte[] salt = NewSalt();
string hashedPassword = HashPassword("passwordInTheClear", salt);
// Add/update the admin-user with hashed password and salt.
```

The hashing-function:

```
public static string HashPassword(string password, byte[] salt)
{
    // derive a 256-bit subkey (use HMACSHA1 with 10,000 iterations)
    return Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
        password: password,
        salt: salt,
        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
        iterationCount: 10000,
        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
}
```

The salt-generator:

```
public static byte[] NewSalt()
{
    // generate a 128-bit salt using a secure PRNG
    byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(salt);
    }
    return salt;
}
```

When a user is trying to log in to the system, I am hashing the entered password from the login form, using the same hash function and the same salt, and comparing it to the hashed password stored in the database:

```
// (I have separated out the password check from the linq query just for debugging purposes)
AdminUser au = await db.AdminUsers
    .Where(u =>
        u.Email1 == loginForm.UserName)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(au.PasswordSalt);
string hashedEnteredPassword = HashPassword(loginForm.Password, salt);
if (au.Password == hashedEnteredPassword)
{
    // Success!
}
```

But the stored and entered password does not match.

Example:

```
In the database:
Unhashed password: 1234
Salt: Cda6ZgNVluChtzseyq9uMQ==
Hashed password: PKzE3rr9CGGmVW3UJS1N7mqrXmzni3hsqyCtP8lrehE=

In the login form:
Entered, unhashed password: 1234
Salt: Cda6ZgNVluChtzseyq9uMQ==
Hashed password: WwYUZqV1GfuRKEitpRdKDjTMEGWy+1nYzpkWI+eZPB0=
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I hope you have a reason to store the encrypted password instead of a password hash. Just mentioning this because, for the purpose outlined in your question, a hash would be the better option.

Comment: @not2savvy I was under the impression that hashing an encrypting was just two different names for the same thing. I have just named my encryption method `EncryptPassword()`. I could have called it `HashPassword()`. Or have I missed something?

Comment: o yes, then indeed you missed something. Hashing is like a checksum, and it is irreversible. Therefore, it’s advantage is that the password cannot be decrypted if someone hacks your database or in a MITM attack, but it is still perfectly good for authentication purposes. However, it looks like you are actually hashing, not encrypting, so your method name is misleading.

Comment: @not2savvy I see. I have changed the naming now. Thanks for the insight! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting your salt from the database as ASCII, while the salt in your example is clearly Base64. You just have to replace `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(au.PasswordSalt)` with `Convert.FromBase64String(au.PasswordSalt)` and call it a day.

```
byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Cda6ZgNVluChtzseyq9uMQ==");
string encryptedPassword = EncryptPassword("1234", salt);
Console.WriteLine(encryptedPassword);
```

will give you `WwYUZqV1GfuRKEitpRdKDjTMEGWy+1nYzpkWI+eZPB0=`, while

```
byte[] salt = Convert.FromBase64String("Cda6ZgNVluChtzseyq9uMQ==");
string encryptedPassword = EncryptPassword("1234", salt);
Console.WriteLine(encryptedPassword);
```

gives `PKzE3rr9CGGmVW3UJS1N7mqrXmzni3hsqyCtP8lrehE=`.